# Assign to common variable inside foreach and doParallel

Tags: r, keras, foreach, doparallel

I am using `doParallel` and `foreach` packages to train 400 small Keras models of a data set I have.

```
#1. Pre-make a blank data frame to be filled with values in the loop
Summary<-data.frame(ticker=character(), Today=numeric(), Tommorow=numeric(), MAPE=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#2. Initialize cores to work
registerDoParallel(detectCores()-1)

#3. Implement for loop with parallel
foreach (i=1:400, .combine=c, .packages = c("keras", "tensorflow","dplyr","data.table")) %dopar% {
          ... code that filters data dynamically on [i] and fits the NN model...
          Summary[i,]<-c(tickers[i],
                         as.numeric(Predict[length(Predict)]),
                         model%>%predict(PredictorsT)%>%as.numeric(),
                         MAPE)
}
```

The parallel process runs but at the end of the loop the Summary data frame remains blank which menas that each iteration is not able to populate the data. How may I achive this?

Comment: You cannot save the results globally inside the loop, you need to save them outside the loop with `res=foreach (...)` and a return statement inside the loop.

Comment: OK. Suspected that to be the issue. How should I code the return statement in the loop to prepare the summary data I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your result in a return statement.

```
Summary = foreach (i=1:400, .combine=c, .packages = c("keras", "tensorflow","dplyr","data.table")) %dopar% {
          ... code that filters data dynamically on [i] and fits the NN model...
          return(c(tickers[i],
                   as.numeric(Predict[length(Predict)]),
                   model%>%predict(PredictorsT)%>%as.numeric(),
                   MAPE))
```

Your combine probably should be `.combine=rbind`

Comment: No need for `return` which, in R, means “abort function execution prematurely”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Isn't that true for other languages as well? I agree that it is not strictly necessary, since R would return the last result by default, but this way it is more explicit / easier to read.

Comment: No. In most other languages, `return x` means “this function returns the value x”, and functions that don’t do this don’t have a return value. But in R **every function has a value**. Once you recognise that, using `return` isn’t any more explicit, it’s just redundant.

Comment: @user2974951 I've used `.combine=rbind`. You can adjust your answer :)

Comment: @nba2020 No, we can categorically exclude that `return` is needed here (just to be 120% sure I just tested it). You must have changed something else.

Comment: Maybe the fact that I have few lines more at the end of the loop makes the return neseccary in my case

Comment: @nba2020 That doesn’t make sense. Code after `return` isn’t executed, so you should remove those lines, and then `return` is no longer necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I removed the lines and indeed `return` is not needed anymore. Thanks a lot as  I didn't know those lines weren't executed